# Using the index of a for loop in a string

Tags: c++, root-framework

I have a little problem but have no idea how to solve it.
I want to use the index from a for loop to get the different histograms in my root files. I have read the root files correctly and I know that the error that I get has something to do with the index in my string. But I don’t know how to do it correctly. I tried using `Form()` but it does not work.

The names of my histograms in the root files are: `bin_1_h0_01`, `bin_2_h0_01` and so on until `bin_512_h0_01`. That is the reason why I need the index.

```
TFile* simHistograms = TFile::Open("sim_output_histograms.root", "READ");
TFile* dataHistograms = TFile::Open("data_output_histograms.root", "READ");

for(int i {1}; i < 513; i++){

    TH1F* sim = (TH1F*)simHistograms->Get(Form("bin_%i_h0_01", i));
    TH1F* data = (TH1F*)dataHistograms->Get(Form("bin_%i_h0_01", i));

    sim->SetDirectory(0);
    data->SetDirectory(0);

    ...
}
```

The error message i get is:

```
/../analyzeData_plot.cpp:33:9: warning: null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument [-Wnonnull]
        sim->SetDirectory(0);
        ^~~
```

---

*ROOT Version:* 6.28/04
*Platform:* Ubuntu 20.04.2
*Compiler:* g++ 9.4.0

---

Comment: There is no iterator in this code, and no error checking to make sure `Open()` and `Get()` are not returning null pointers.

Comment: It seems that in `sim->SetDirectory(0)`, `0` is wrong - it should be a pointer instead (maybe to `char`).

Comment: FWIW, You are using an *index* variable, not really an iterator.  Iterators are more like pointers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh sorry, I'm kinda new to c++ and learning it right now. Thanks for the tip with the error checking. Thats a good idea.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sorry, you're right. Index is what I meant

Comment: @RemyLebeau 0 is a valid pointer in general, but here the warning clearly says: `null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument`. There must be a compiler-specific C++ extension used by the library that makes this warning possible.

Comment: @Eugene there is indeed such an extension - gcc has [`__attribute__(nonnull, (...))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). And that was my first thought here, too. But, according to the [`SetDirectory()`](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTH1.html#a0367fe04ae8709fd4b82795d0a5462c3) documentation (and examples, and internal source code), `nullptr` is a valid input value, so it would not make sense for the library to mark `SetDirectory()`'s parameter as `nonnull`.  So, something else is going on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes because,you are passing a null argument to the `SetDirectory()` function, and this error is likely caused by the fact that the histogram objects `sim` and `data` are not being retrieved correctly from the root files, so you can edit the `Form()` function call to correctly format the histogram names because the `Form()` function returns a formatted string, and you can use it directly as the argument for `Get()`!

let me show you how :

```
TFile* simHistograms = TFile::Open("sim_output_histograms.root", "READ");
TFile* dataHistograms = TFile::Open("data_output_histograms.root", "READ");

for (int i = 1; i <= 512; i++) {
    TString histName = Form("bin_%d_h0_01", i);

    TH1F* sim = (TH1F*)simHistograms->Get(histName);
    TH1F* data = (TH1F*)dataHistograms->Get(histName);

    if (sim && data) {
        sim->SetDirectory(0);
        data->SetDirectory(0);

        //you can use the histograms as needed
    } else {
        //handle the case where the histograms are not found
    }
}

simHistograms->Close();
dataHistograms->Close();
```

Comment: `simHistograms` and `dataHistograms` can be null.

Comment: @273K Why do you immediately give a negative points when you see a problem in the answer? I think it's better to give others a chance to make up for it, my friend! If simHistograms and dataHistograms are null, it means that there was an error opening the root files and he should check if the files were opened successfully before proceeding with the for loop.

Comment: @Freeman Thank you so much! It worked! I probably did not really understand what `Form()` does. Thank you!

Comment: Note: The [documentation](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/TString_8h.html#a4dbc5637d55cac5d3e8b9a9df747b59f) for `Form` even has a warning about this.  Since `Form` uses an internal static buffer, `Get` may clobber the result before consuming it.

Comment: The **only** thing this answer provides that the OP wasn't doing is checking the return value of `Get()` for null pointers. Nothing effectively changed regarding the use of `Form()` at all. Pulling it out of the function calls into its own statement is merely an optimization, not a requirement.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your kind words. Please provide the correct answer so that we can all benefit from it. I make no claims and have only shared what I thought was appropriate.